# Trouble with torch SpatialFullConvolution dimensions

Tags: torch, conv-neural-network

I'm creating a convolutional neural network with torch. My neural network has a number of convolution layers and I'm trying to add in some deconvolution layers. However, I'm having trouble predicting the dimensions of the tensor after the first SpatialFullConvolution layer.

I'm using a kernel of size 4 with spacing of 2 and padding of 1:

```
model:add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(256, 128, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0))
```

Going into this layer I have a 256x4x4 tensor. According to the [torch documentation](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#nn.SpatialConvolution) I can find the width and height of the resulting tensor with

> owidth  = (width  - 1) * dW - 2*padW + kW + adjW
>
> oheight = (height - 1) * dH - 2*padH + kH + adjH

Using the above code, I think I should be getting a 128x8x8 tensor. But my code is throwing an error and says that it's a 128x10x10 tensor.

Is the documentation wrong or am I just going crazy here? How can I take my 256x4x4 tensor and get my 128x8x8 tensor with a SpatialFullConvolution layer?

Comment: With latest torch/nn version (at the time of writing) `nn.SpatialFullConvolution(256, 128, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1):forward(torch.Tensor(256, 4, 4)):size()` gives `128x8x8`.

Comment: @deltheil Thanks! I've updated my version of torch and it seems to be working now.